# Exception when deselecting NSTableView row

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I'm a bit lost with this... It seems I can't find why I can't deselect rows from my NSTableView.  I allowed empty selection in Interface Builder but as soon as I call deselectRow: or deselectedAll:, I get an exception.

For example, with this code:

```
NSLog(@"Currently selected row index: %ld", [self.tableView selectedRow]);
[self.tableView deselectRow:[self.tableView selectedRow]];
```

I get:

```
2011-09-05 MyApp[18939:707] Currently selected row index: 1
2011-09-05 MyApp[18939:707] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]
```

I even get the same kind of error if I call deselectRow: with a hard coded value (say 0) for testing.  So I suppose the error originates from the binding with my NSArrayController or something?

Comment: the exception occurs possibly with some code reacting to the deselection...do you have some code like that ?

Comment: What ended up being the cause?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A very long integer like that usually means a memory address is being translated into an integer. That in turn is usually caused by passing an object to a scalar variable.

In IB, look at the `selected object` bindings for the interface elements. At some point, you handing an object to off to `deselectRow` instead of a scalar integer.

Answer (score 0):

my solution (so raw, I know)

```
 if(row != UINT64_MAX)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling `NSTableView#deselectRow` inside `NSTableViewDelegate#tableViewSelectionDidChange`, which triggers another call to the `tableViewSelectionDidChange` method. In that second call, the `NSTableView#selectedRow` property equals `-1`, which is an invalid value to pass to `deselectRow`.

To avoid that, simply wrap the `deselectRow` call with a `selectedRow >= 0` condition.